# Liferay auto login

Tags: authentication, liferay

I must use Liferay 5.2.3 and tomcat-5.5.27

I have to login user programmatically.
I create a portlet and a file "view.jsp"

I found and tried this code:

```
String username = String.valueOf(user.getUserId());
String password = user.getPassword();

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("j_username", username);
session.setAttribute("j_password", password);
session.setAttribute("j_remoteuser", username);
```

I find the user by id but i'm not signed in liferay.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but it's totally wrong way.

You need an hook plugin, have to implement an AutoLogin based class with a custom portal.properties to setup auto.login.hooks property.

Follow this discussion: https://community.liferay.com/it/forums/-/message_boards/message/114134